# golang http handler wrapping/chaining

Tags: go, handler

I am using golang http handler wrapping like so

```
router := mux.NewRouter()

wrapper1(h http.Handle, ip1 string)    
wrapper2(h http.Handler, ip2 string)    
wrapper3(h http.Handler, ip3 string)    
wrapper4(h http.Handler, ip4 string)    
wrapper5(h http.Handler, ip5 string)

router.Handle("/route1", wrapper5(wrapper4(wrapper3(wrapper2(wrapper3, 
    "input1"), "input2"), "input3"), "input4"), "input5")
```

Now if I need another wrapper, I can chain it.

My qs: Is this level of handler chaining a good way or is there a better/another way to implement handler chaining?

Comment: The package [`alice`](https://godoc.org/github.com/justinas/alice) provides helpers for exactly this.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/urfave/negroni which is a very popular Middleware wrapper. It also provides some basics

Comment: I recommend alice and this reading https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/middlewares-golang-best-practices-examples/

Comment: You don't need any third-party packages to do this. Your example implementation is perfectly fine. If you're always going to use all the wrappers, you can write a helper to chain them all so you don't have to repeat the same five-wrapper chain for every handler.

Comment: @Adrian: That sounds like a viable idea. Thank you

Comment: @mg03 You can make this piece of code look a bit better by putting the result into a variable after calling a wrapper: `w1 := wrapper1(orig, "p1")` then `w2 := wrapper2(w1, "p2")` an so on... And I agree with Adrian that you absolutely don't need fancy third party packages for this very simple task.